# Failing Hard drive - root of all problems?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, shutdown, overheating

So I have a question for those who are a little more clued up on this than myself.

I have a laptop which is about 2 years old now and has been plaguing me with various issues for some time. The most common issues I get are overheating, complete halts, and random shutdowns.

The difference between overheating shutdowns and random ones are that when it overheats, it shuts down telling me that it's reached a critical temperature, whilst random is like someone pulled the power out and just goes pooof and off it is.

At first I thought I might have bad ventilation, serious overheating on the CPU, RAM and things like that. But I happened to stumble upon a small issue being mentioned on a hard drive test.

Over the last few days things went from bad to worse.

For instance, last night I had booted the laptop from cold and opened the Downloads folder (which was slow, unresponsive and buggy for a few seconds) and then opened a video file (something i've done 1000x without issues) only this time I heard the startup music but the screen was blank, so trying to close the app, I discovered the laptop had completely frozen, no mouse movement and no response to any keyboard, so I was forced to do a restart.

Needless ton say, I'm now doing a `dd` clone to another hard drive I have.

I want to say before I actually ask the question, that I had opened up the laptop a few weeks ago and to my surprise saw nothing wrong at all, no dust, no hint of burn marks, everything looked completely in tact.

My question is, if my harddrive is the problem and it's starting to fail, can that also be responsible for heating issues?

Comment: I'd like to thank all of you for all your great suggestions. After having opened the casing once more, I did notice light patches on the motherboard.
The laptop did become extremely hot most of the time to the point where it burnt your hand after long use near the fan output.
I decided to invest in a new laptop and throw a server on the old laptop to test my terminal skills on.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, if my harddrive is the problem and it's starting to fail, can that also be responsible for heating issues?

I won't say it's impossible but I've never seen it. Most disks are quite a long way away from the important parts. I'm sure some know-it-all will come along with an example where the disk is mounted on the CPU as its heatsink, but that isn't common. The HD is usually nice and accessible for maintenance, upgrades, etc.

I would sooner blame the repetitive overheating doing damage. I've had a few thermal casualties over a couple of decades and not one left a scorch mark. The slot-CPU casing melted once (that was fun) but that was the only time I've ever *seen* evidence that the system got too hot.

And remember there's nothing to say that this is just one issue. Disks fail all the time. Laptops cook themselves all the time. It could be possible that both are happening to you.

Comment: Yea, the hd isn't going to cause the cpu to overheat, though the reverse may be true.  A frequently overheating CPU could push the hd temp higher and increase its odds of failing, so they could be related in that way.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to test run the laptop while it is open you night check the heat pipe. its the flattened tube that runs from the CPU to the vents in the back or side on the unit, i have encountered at least one machine whos heat pipe leaked out the gas and the CPU got hot to the point of thermal shutdown but the fan exaust was still cold. the heat pipe wasn't transferring the heat away!